# Condition filter is disabling price range filter in eBay API

Tags: javascript, json, ebay-api

When I specify a condition filter in the eBay API url, it disables the price rangefilter. How can I make it so that both filters work together properly? Code is below.

```
<script src=http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SECURITY-APPNAME=*API KEY GOES HERE*&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords&REST-PAYLOAD&outputSelector=AspectHistogram&itemFilter(0).name=Condition&itemFilter(0).value(0)=New&sortOrder=PricePlusShippingLowest&itemFilter(0).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(0).value=500.00&itemFilter(0).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(0).paramValue=USD&itemFilter(1).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(1).value=200.00&itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency&itemFilter.name=ListingType&itemFilter.value=FixedPrice&itemFilter(1).paramValue=USD&keywords=iphone%205%2016gb&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=6>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clearly enumerate your itemFilters. You have at least 2 versions of itemFilter(0).name= with MaxPrice overwriting your Condition filter. You also have an itemFilter without an enumeration at all (itemFilter.value=FixedPrice), probably altering things as well. Take your time to build those filters carefully 1 at a time.

Also, while you're at it, have all the itemFilter's together in your URL, in order, and at the end of the URL (in other words, move the pagination params and sortOrder before all itemFilter params). I've seen cases where this matters.

Also get your SERVICE-VERSION= to be current -- 1.12.0 . That can only help.

Comment: Does this mean I should make it so that they all have the same number? I tried enumerating them all with 0, but max price and condition still don't seem to be working. What do these numbers mean?

Comment: No, they should NOT be all the same number. Look at the example for ListingType here in the eBay docs: http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/types/ItemFilterType.html#ListingType  See how for that filter, they all use itemFilter(0) ? Then, the values enumerate 0,1,2. It's 1 filter with multiple values. ... Let's say you wanted to also use another filter as well. It would be &itemFilter(1) appended on your URL. And the values would STILL start with 0,1,2,3,etc.